# strptime() does not convert string to datetime object in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, strptime

I am getting an exception when I run the following code which I can not explain:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime("2018-04-02", format = "%Y-%m-%d")

TypeError: strptime() takes no keyword arguments
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `format =` keyword, the second argument is positional **only**:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2018-04-02", "%Y-%m-%d")
datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 2, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Why not? How do they make this distinction? I look at the function signature and I find :
`def strptime(cls, date_string, format):`

How come I can't name the keyword arguments here?

Comment: @Aetos: because the method is defined in C code, and _most_ native functions and methods are positional-only. Generally speaking, for code written in C, supporting arguments both as positional and as keyword arguments carries a performance penalty so such support is rarely added.